# onchange event is not firing in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, input, onchange, eventhandler

I want to select two files from the local system using HTML5 input element. I have written code as follows which is working fine in firefox but is not working in chrome. The onchange event is not firing whether i use addEventListener method or follow old style of input1.onchange = function name. As per my requirement i need to select two files one after another in one case and in all other cases i need to select only a single file. Can you let me know how to make it work on chrome also.

html snippet

```
<button id="openfolder"></button>
```

JavaScript snippet

```
function init() {
    document.getElementById('openfolder').addEventListener("click",
    menu_onclick,false);
}

//I am not appending the element to the document.
function menu_onclick(ev) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.id = 'selectFile';
    input.type = 'file';                            
    input.addEventListener("change",file_onchange,false);
    input.click();
}

function file_onchange(ev){
    var input1 = document.createElement('input');
    input1.id = 'selectXMLFile';
    input1.type = 'file';
    input1.addEventListener("change",xmlSelect,false);
    input1.click();
}
```

Comment: You have only defined the `init()` function, yet have not called the `init()` function. Call the init function on load.

Comment: Just to show how button tag is written i included that statment. I am calling init method in body tag like <body onload="init();">. The above Java Script is working fine with firefox but not with chrome.

Comment: What i observed was in firefox when I am triggering click event in menu_onclick function it is firing onchange event. And again when I am triggering click event in onchange event handler it is trigger onchange event again and the corresponding event handler called 'xmlSelect' is getting executed. But in chrome, the first onchange event only is getting fired. Second time executing input1.click method is not triggering onchange event as in the case of firefox.

Comment: Can you add the complete code to the question, parts of the code are missing. The function `xmlSelect` is not included in the above code

Comment: That's weird it works on FF... Normally, you need user input to perform a `HTMLInputElement.click()`.

Comment: The xmlSelect File is as follows. function xmlSelect(ev) {

    var files = ev.target.files;
    var xmlfile = files[0];
    console.log("xmlfile name is " + xmlfile.name);
    }

Comment: Just now i tried below code in w3schools website editor which is working fine with FF but not with chrome. <!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body><button id="filedata" onclick="myFunction(event);">Select File</button><script>
function selectFile1(ev) { alert("ok"); }
function selectFile(ev) { var in1 = document.createElement('input');in1.id = "sfILE1";in1.type = "file"; in1.addEventListener("change",selectFile1,false); in1.click();}
function myFunction(ev) {var x = document.createElement("input"); x.id="sFile";x.type = "file";x.addEventListener("change",selectFile);x.click();}</script></body></html>